# If 1/(a+b) = 1/a + 1/b , what is the solution for z=a/b?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

If 1/(a+b) = 1/a + 1/b , what is the solution for z=a/b?

I made an attempt to use the formula for the solution of an equation of a complex number but I don't know how to use it in this case.

Comment: Why not set $z=\frac ab$ so that $a=bz$ and just clear fractions? Solve the quadratic, and bingo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are equivalent formulations
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
 \frac{1}{a+b} &=& \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}\\
1 &=& \frac{a+b}{a} + \frac{a+b}{b}\\
1 &=& 2 + \frac{b}{a} + \frac{a}{b}\\
0  &=& 1 + \frac{1}{z} + z\\
0 &=& z^2 + z+ 1\\
0 &=& \left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{4}\\
z &=& -\frac{1}{2} \pm  \frac{i}{2} \sqrt 3
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:if $$\frac{1}{a+b}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$$ then we have $$ab=(a+b)^2$$ or $$0=a^2+ab+b^2$$ this can be written as $$\frac{a}{b}+1+\frac{b}{a}=0$$ thus when we set $$t=\frac{a}{b}$$ then we get?
we also Need $$a,b\ne 0$$ and $$a+b\ne 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Just to be different:

$\frac 1a + \frac 1b = \frac 1{a+b}$

$(a+b)(\frac 1a + \frac 1b) = 1$

$1 + \frac ab + \frac ba + 1 = 1$

$1 + z + \frac 1z = 0$

$z^2 + z + 1 = 0$

$(z-1)(z^2 + z + 1) = z^3 - 1 = 0*(z-1)$

$z^3 = 1$ but clearly $z \ne 1$ as $1^2 + 1 + 1 \ne 0$.

$z$ a cube root of unity but not the real cube root of unity.

$z = e^{\pm \frac {2\pi}3i}= \cos(\pm \frac {2\pi}3) + i \sin(\pm \frac {2\pi}3) = -\frac 12 \pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$

=====

Or to be really different:

$a =\frac 1{\frac 1{a+b}} - b$

$= \frac 1{\frac 1a + \frac 1b} - b$

$= \frac {ab}{a+b} -b$

So $a^2 + ba = ab - b^2 - ab$

$a^2 + ab + b^2 = 0$

So $a = \frac {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4b^2}}2$

$=\frac {-b \pm |b|\sqrt {-3}}2$

$= \frac { -b \pm b i\sqrt{3}}2$

So $\frac ab = \frac {\frac { -b \pm bi \sqrt {3}}2}b= \frac { -1 \pm  i\sqrt {3}}2$

Comment: You might stop after $z^2+z+1=0$: it's known from high school that its roots are the non-real cubic roots of unity.

Comment: If I can stop there, I can stop before the question was asked.   It might have been known from high school, but it isn't known who knows it was known since high school.  It was certainly known since high school how to do this problem so.... I'm confused why you think this question was asked in the first place.

Comment: IOW, it is not known before high school that this is known since high school...

Comment: FWIW, I didn't learn it in high school.  And and "algebra-precalculus" tag is not what I'd assume is necessarily post-high school.   And when it comes to the average level of math knowledge and comfort, "high school" is not universal